# Changing Platform at start of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio solution that needs to be compiled with an already defined x86, instead of the default "Any CPU".  When I clone the repo or do a worktree, the solution starts with "Any CPU" platform and I tend to forget it, resulting in loads of building errors.

Is there a way to changing to that platform when Visual Studio opens for the first time, without storing the config setting in a .suo or .user (which I don't want to add to version control as not recommended).

I am looking for options to run a script or similar to automatically switch the solution platform to x86 when starting Visual Studio as follow pic

[image: picture]

I use VS2019 and will switch to VS2022 soon.

Comment: Changing the solution platform is not the appropriate way to do this in C# or VB.NET projects.  Matters a great deal for C++ projects, not for managed ones since it is the just-in-time compiler that locks-in the architecture at runtime.  Get rid of all added platforms so only AnyCPU remains, then right-click the main startup project and use Properties > Build > "Platform target" = x86.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant  - My solution is a mix of C++ and C#, ideally I'd like to start the solution with the x86 default.  My main project is a C++ one